# How to set provisioning profile manually in Xcode8?

Tags: ios, xcode8, provisioning-profile

As you know, in Xcode8, the provisioning profile is deprecated, and there is a newer provisioning profile.

[image]

But the newer it is `Automatic`, and can not choose provisioning profile like the deprecated one.

So, how to set the Adhoc provisioning profile manually in Xcode8？

Comment: Remove the `Development Team` you will be able to see all the Profiles, after you choose and set Profiles and Certificates, set the Team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seek out:

In the Target -> General -> Signing, to uncheck Automatically manage siging, then I can choose by myself.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To set provisioning profile manually in Xcode 8, go to target and switch to General tab and there deselect the 'Automatically manage signing'. After it you can set the provisioning profile both for debug and release.

[see this picture for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWHAR.png)

Answer (score 1):

I am using Xcode 8 Beta 2.

Setup Provisioning Profile Manually in Xcode 8 version
1. Open Xcode version 8.0 and above.
2. Select Project Name from Left menu.
3. Select TARGETS option in left adjutant pane.
4. Set your **Bundle Identifier** name
5. Uncheck Automatic Manage Signin
6. Select your Provisioning profile in SIGNIN(DEBUG) and SIGNIN(RELEASE) section.
7. Please keep in mind that you already have installed provisioning profile in Xcode. (Development and Distribution profile.)

[image]